# What is the different between generating expression and infinite expansion?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

What is the different between generating expression and infinite expansion?

I can't figure it on my own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a sequence, like $a_k$, it's *generating function* is a (formal) expression of the form:
$$
A(z) = \sum_{k \ge 0} a_k z^k
$$
(instead of $z^k$ sometimes other base functions are used). Note that this is purely formal, $A(z)$ doesn't have to define a function anywhere (a favorite of mine is $\sum_{n \ge 0} n! z^n$, which does have it's uses). You can very well define such formal expansions on things that aren't numbers and use them. Wilf says the generating function is a clothesline on which to hang the coefficients for display.

An *infinite expansion* is for example an infinite series like the well-known:
$$
\frac{1}{1 - z} = \sum_{n \ge 0} z^n
$$
Here you are interested in the expansion as a way of computing the function, or some such.

The distinction is blurry. Precisely much of the usefulness of generating functions lies in that stuying them as expansions of certain functions you extract information on the coefficients, which is your main objective.